# How azure ad auth user with oauth2 after enable MFA

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory

Now my app use OAUTH2 auth azure ad user. Before I get access token by user name and password, it works fine without MFA. But after azure ad user enable MFA, it will report error :

> "{ error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to acces \'00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000\'".

So after azare ad enalbe MFA, how auth azure ad user with user name and password in nodejs?

Comment: You cannot. User needs to do interactive authentication with Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

> So after azare ad enalbe MFA, how auth azure ad user with user name
>   and password in nodejs?

The authentication method you are using is a non-interactive one, while an MFA-enabled account always needs extra interaction. They are conflicted, so suggest you consider to use an interactive strategy or disable MFA.